# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [ ] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

Tags: junit, spring-tool-suite

I fixed my test like that:

```
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {CoreTestSpringConfiguration.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

public class NewStudentTest {


    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;



    @MockBean
    SaveStudentCommand saveStudentCommand;


    @Before
    public void setupMockMvc() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(wac)
                .build();
    }


    @Test
    public void createStudentTest() throws Exception {

        String jsonLineTest = "[{username:\"532g326\"} ,{name:\"Franco\"} ,{username:\"432ih4j\"} ,{name:\"Ciccio\"} ]";

        Student s1 = new Student();
        Student s2 = new Student();
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        ((Student) s1).setUsername("532g326");
        ((Student) s1).setName("Franco");
        ((Student) s2).setUsername("432ih4j");
        ((Student) s2).setName("Ciccio");

        students.add(s1);
        students.add(s2);


        when(saveStudentCommand.execute()).thenReturn(jsonLineTest);


        MvcResult result=mockMvc.perform(post("/credentials/student")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(jsonLineTest))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())   
                .andReturn();

        String content=result.getResponse().getContentAsString();



    }  


}
```

and now, according to this new configuration, the test fails, showing:
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was <404>.

I suppose this answer is caused by the same problem shown in console:

No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/credentials/student] in DispatcherServlet with name '';

I cannot understand the last message above. Which DispatcherServlet cannot be found? How can I fix this problem? Thx in advance

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your `CoreTestSpringConfiguration` class, is there a mapping for `/credentials/student`? I would be more familiar with XML config but it's mostly the same

Comment: The issue is that I'm new to Spring and I don't know how to configure my CoreTestSpringConfiguration class. Could you please suggest me any guide/tutorials to learn how to do it? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty good tutorial on the [Spring.io Getting Started pages for testing requests](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/), if you're just starting to learn Spring I would start here if you're doing your tests.

It goes through a step-by-step process to build up the entire test suite for the HTTP requests and should help you. (They introduce MockMvc halfway through the guide and use the `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotation instead of doing any configuration themselves)